# How do you edit start and end comments in ruamel.yaml?

Tags: ruamel.yaml

In ruamel.yaml, we have the ability to edit the start and end comments of an object using `yaml_set_start_comment` and `yaml_end_comment_extend`. I have some a couple questions about these:

- Is there a way to append to or edit an existing start comment? (In particular, I am interested in editing the comment at the very start of a yaml document.) It seems like I would have to reach into the `ca` field of the ruamel objects to get the existing start comment, but this seems suboptimal for other reasons, e.g. I might not want to pin the ruamel version I'm using.
- How do you use `yaml_end_comment_extend`? I notice the source code uses `extend` instead of `append`, so I've tried passing in `"str"` and `["str"]`, but neither one ultimately gets dumped.

Comment: You will not be able to do this without pinning the ruamel.yaml version. neither the .ca attribute nor any methods are part of an official API and can change with the next minor version.